# How can I create a modifier that requires the msg.sender be one of multiple addresses?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, addresses

I apologize if this has been asked already.  It seems like a very basic question but I cannot find an answer to it.  Every example of using a modifier to create a "ownerOnly" function uses the "owner = msg.sender" in the constructor, but what if I want to allow a few different addresses/people to modify a contract or execute a function.  How do I write the modifier to do this?  I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
modifier onlyMembers {
    require(msg.sender == owner || "0xdaa602d3e2aeea57ee753e40ac1639ed20e3174f" || "0x3147ca98dc9235e38c4cd3f82315332294e9234a");
    _;
}
```

I also tried using checksum addresses and created new, global address variables called "member1" and "member2" which point to those addresses like this:

```
contract Autos {

address owner;
address member1;
address member2;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    member1 = 0xDAA602D3E2Aeea57eE753E40AC1639eD20e3174F;
    member2 = 0x3147cA98dc9235e38c4cd3F82315332294e9234A;
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner || member1 || member2);
_;

}
```

Remix tells me "Operator || not compatible with types bool and address", but I feel like there must be a way to "or" the addresses somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost on the right path!

The correct syntax would be

```
modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == member1 || msg.sender == member2);
    _;
}
```

While that would work, it would get a bit repetitive, so you could opt for something like the following which would easily allow multiple members and a single owner owner.

```
    address public owner;
    mapping (address => bool) public members;


    modifier onlyMembers() {
        require(msg.sender == owner || members[msg.sender] == true);
        _;
    }
```

The above is very extendable, and would allow you to update the members mapping as needed (removing/adding members) and the `onlyMembers()` modifier would still work.

edit:

One thing to keep in mind about evaluating `boolean` values, when you are evaluate a single condition the following syntax works `require(someValue);` however when evaluating multiple boolean conditions, you will need to be  explicit about the condition, see:

`require(someValueOne == false && someValueTwo == true && someValueThree == false);`

Comment: Thank you.  I am guessing, as well, that while "require(someValue)" would work, even this would only work if I needed someValue to be true.  In other words, if I wanted it to be false, I would have to write "require(someValue == false)"?

Comment: you could write `require(!somevalue)`

Comment: Yea Jaime is correct `require(!someValue)` would work, but if multiple `require(someValueOne == false && someValueTwo == false);`

Answer (score -1):

```
contract Autos {

address owner;
address[] members;
uint counter = 1;
mapping (address => bool) public owners;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    members = [0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c];
    for (uint i=0; i lessthan members.length ; i++)
    {
     owners[members[i]]=true;
   }
}

function incCounter() onlyOwner {
       counter++;
   }
    function showCount() view returns(uint){
        return counter;
    }

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(owners[msg.sender]);
_;

}  
}
```

It will work fine.

Keep in mind that what ever the variable you want to use it should be stored in storage or memory allocated to a contract. It will be stored only if the transaction is executed.

This code will help you figure your own logic.

Comment: This is very unsafe, and if just one member becomes malicious they can overflow the members array, thereby creating the ability to alter other records.